# How to select individual elements with javascript here?

Tags: javascript

See here: https://siteweb.synergieetvitalite.com/monportfolio/

I would like the smartphone and laptop to come close togheter as the user moves his mouse. The code i am using :

HTML:

```html
<div class="scene">
      <div data-speed="51" class="layer layer-middle"></div>
      <div data-speed="81" class="layer layer-top"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script> document.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);

    function parallax(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.querySelectorAll('.layer-middle').forEach((layer) => {
        let speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed');
        layer.style.transform = `translateX(${e.clientX * speed / 1000}px)`;
      })
    } 

</script>
```

I tried to modify this so that .layer-top moves to the right, but then the layer-middle stopped moving alltogheter, probablement because of SelectorAll or forEach. I don't really know javascript so I wasn't able to simply make the function work for each element individually.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the devtools console?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the `foreach` and select each element separately like below. So this way you will move the laptop to right and the phone to left or vice versa.
I've changed your code a little. Try it and let me know if its what which you are looking for.

```
<script> document.addEventListener('mousemove', parallax);

    function parallax(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      laptop = document.querySelector('.layer-middle');
      let speed = laptop.getAttribute('data-speed');
      laptop.style.transform = `translateX(${e.clientX * speed / 1000}px)`;
      phone = document.querySelector('.layer-top');
      phone.style.transform = `translateX(${-1*e.clientX * speed / 1000}px)`;
    } 

</script>
```